# AES key size of 512 doesn't work

Tags: java, encryption, react-native, aes, realm

I am trying to write a native module to generate/store AES keys for realm encryption. For the test application I wrote (when I used 512 key size), I get the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidParameterException: Wrong keysize: must be equal to 128, 192 or 256
>       at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESKeyGenerator.engineInit(AESKeyGenerator.java:93)
>       at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.init(KeyGenerator.java:517)
>       at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.init(KeyGenerator.java:494)

The code I am using is:

```
KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
keyGen.init(512);
SecretKey secretKey = keyGen.generateKey();
final int AES_KEYLENGTH = 512;  
byte[] iv = new byte[AES_KEYLENGTH / 8];    
SecureRandom prng = new SecureRandom();
prng.nextBytes(iv);
Cipher aesCipherForEncryption = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7PADDING");
```

Can someone please let me know what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: AES currently only accepts 128, 192 or 256

Comment: True!, but realm is expecting a 512 bit key for encrypting the database. Is this not the right way to generate a key for encryption?

Comment: @user4122421 I have no idea about realm, but I suspect that the key that you need to pass in, is split into an AES key and a MAC key. It's also possible that it is used completely for AES and is expected to be 64 hex-encoded characters.

Comment: What is it that you want to do? The [first thing in the documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#encryption) shows exactly how a 512-bit key can be generated and set.

Comment: Thanks, Artjom. I want to generate and store in the Android Keystore. I looked at this implementation, but I am not sure how secure is this way of creating a key. Also, my use case is that I need to create multiple keys for different users (may be an alias for the key will help here!). I am already using realm in the react-native application. I don't want to use realm configuration in my native module.

Comment: Artjom, another example I looked at is this public byte[] generateKeyForRealm() {
        final byte[] keyForRealm = new byte[RealmConfiguration.KEY_LENGTH];
        rng.nextBytes(keyForRealm);
        return keyForRealm;
    } If I create a key like this and pass it to the realm used in the react-native, how secure this approach would be? And, I can't save this key in the Android keystore

Comment: The doc linked by @ArtjomB. even says that it is using **AES-256** encryption.

Comment: True, Andreas, but the key size is 64 byte

Comment: @Andreas You can keep going on about a 64-byte key but that will not change the fact that AES does not support a 64-byte key. Not what Realm does with a 64-byte key is a Realm issue, not an AES issue. It is sad that Realm does not provide information about the key, it seems Realm does not want to provide interoperability. Decide if you want to use a library (Realm) that does not provide interoperability information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store a 512-bit key "as an AES key", you can just store two 256-bit AES keys, call them LEFT and RIGHT, for example, and concatenate them before passing to Realm.

As others have pointed out in comments, AES does *not* have 512-bit keys. It may say they are using AES-256 encryption, but I doubt it says anywhere that they are using *512-bit, AES* keys.

I suspect, as @Artjom B. mentions in the comment, that it really is a pair of 256-bit keys, one for encryption and one for mac (e.g. HMAC).

If you want to create a 512-bit key, you can just use SecureRandom. There is nothing special about KeyGenerator that SecureRandom cannot provide for AES keys. You just want to be sure that you are using *cryptographically strong* random data.